# Replacing an old image with a new one. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a function that places an image provided by the input of the user into the body of an html page. When a second input is received I want to replace this picture with the new one. I have attempted to do just this in the below function.

```
function show_image(src, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = 400;
        img.height = 300;
        img.alt = alt;

        var counter;
        var mynodes= new Array();
        mynodes.push(img);
        counter+=1;

        if(counter==1){
            // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
            document.body.appendChild(img);  
        }
        else if(counter!=1)
        {
            var newNode=mynodes[counter-1];
            var oldNode=mynodes[counter-2];
            document.body.replaceChild(newNode,oldNode);
        }
```

Comment: `var counter; counter+=1;` gives you a `NaN` since you never assign a value to counter so it is undefined, and adding 1 to undefined gives you a NaN (not a number). Also since you define the counter inside the function it will never be incremented since it is redefined every time that you call the function.

Comment: Your counter variable is not initialized. `counter+=1;` will just assigned `NaN` to counter. So `counter!=1` will be true, but both `counter-1` and `counter-2` will be NaN, so `newNode` and `oldNode` will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `counter` is a local variable.
Each time the method is called counter is initialized to 0.

Same thing with your `mynodes`variable. It is always going to have only one node in the array.

So you may want to change your logic here. Do you want help rewriting this function?

Comment: No that cleared it up thanks! I will accept when it allows me.

Comment: He doesn't need to refactor this function, he needs to refactor the whole apprach. It makes no sense to replace the img tag at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is totally awkward. As far as I can tell, you could simply change the same img tag instead of changing the whole node each time. There's barely a reason for a function..

[Click here for a live demo.](http://jsbin.com/ObOQibU/1/edit)

```
function changeImg(img, src, alt) {
  //I doubt you even need a function for this.
  img.src = src;
  img.alt = alt;
}

var img = document.createElement('img');
//you could just use a css class instead...
//that's probably better anyway...why does your js care how it looks? 
img.width = 400;
img.height = 300;
document.body.appendChild(img);

changeImg(img, 'http://static.jsbin.com/images/favicon.png', 'image');

var imgSrcInput = document.getElementById('imgSrc');
var imgAltInput = document.getElementById('imgAlt');
var button = document.getElementById('change');

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  changeImg(img, imgSrcInput.value, imgAltInput.value);
});
```

I put together an object oriented example. This makes your logic very reusable and friendly. [Check out the code in action here (click).](http://jsbin.com/OGADaBa/2/edit)

```
window.onload = function() { //usage

  var someElement = document.getElementById('someIdHere');
  var anotherElement = document.getElementById('anotherIdHere');

  imageReplacer.setup({
    element: someElement,
    initSrc: 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRg-icdkibfDt8VE7FkaKZyVUh8SBR4YTGd-2Jz1wZeUVacv4YD8zrvwclN',
    initAlt: 'Starting Image'
  });
  imageReplacer.setup({
    element: anotherIdHere,
    initSrc: 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrHWuOzgYPbsuSF9cYQo3ORkcdIC4-8xaszlCrI3f7arAC7vhV7HwMN_fG',
    initAlt: 'Starting Image'
  });

};


var imageReplacer = { //package up your app
  setup : function(options) {
    //create a new imageReplacer so that each one will operate independently. The "this" pointer will refer to each element's imageReplacer.
    options.element.imageReplacer = Object.create(imageReplacer);
    options.element.imageReplacer.makeReplacer(options);
  },
  makeReplacer : function(options) {
    options.element.className = 'imageReplacer';
    var markup = this.createMarkup();

    this.changeImage(options.initSrc, options.initAlt);

    this.addClick(this.button);

    options.element.appendChild(markup);
  },
  createMarkup : function() {
     var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

    this.srcInput = document.createElement('input');
    this.srcInput.type = 'text';
    this.srcInput.placeholder = 'Image Source';

    this.altInput = document.createElement('input');
    this.altInput.type = 'text';
    this.altInput.placeholder = 'Image Alt';

    this.button = document.createElement('button');
    this.button.textContent = 'Change Image';

    this.imgTag = document.createElement('img');

    frag.appendChild(this.srcInput);
    frag.appendChild(this.altInput);
    frag.appendChild(this.button);
    frag.appendChild(this.imgTag);

    return frag;
  },
  addClick : function(button) {
    var that = this;
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      that.changeImage(that.srcInput, that.altInput);
    });
  },
  changeImage : function(src, alt) {
    this.imgTag.src = src;
    this.imgTag.alt = alt;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a function to dynamically change the picture(which did work), I decided to  hide one picture on my index.html file. And then changed the src with $("#my_image").attr("src","img/fire.gif"); #my_image being the id of the image tag.